# Selecting text area with text area name not working

Tags: jquery

No alert pops out for the given code ! I am new in jQuery and not sure about the **selector of text area using textarea name**. I want the value of text area to print in the alert box.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(":submit").click(function(){
 alert( $("textarea[name=textEditor]").val(); );
 });
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_" value="Add" />
<textarea name="textEditor" rows="20" cols="60" > </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial Error,

```
........ .val(); );
//-------------^
```

Please remove that `semi-colon` over there, it would cause syntax error.

Try to prevent the default functionality of the submit button,

```
$(":submit").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 alert( $("textarea[name=textEditor]").val());
});
```

The Base functionality of the submit button is to submit the form, If we use `event.preventDefault()` would stop the button to proceed its base action.

Answer (score 3):

Try to prevent from postbacking the page using jquery prevent default.

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e){
 alert($("textarea[name=textEditor]").val());
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` after val():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(":submit").click(function(){
 alert( $("textarea[name=textEditor]").val() );
 });
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U4gVq/)

Answer (score 1):

your code is ok but there is one `;` you added after `val()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(":submit").click(function(){
// alert( $("textarea[name=textEditor]").val(); );
//   remove ; after val();
 alert( $("textarea[name=textEditor]").val());
 });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ficakiyi/1/

Answer (score 1):

The below 2 alternatives would work!

**Alternative 1:**

```
var textAreaValue = $("textarea[name=textEditor]").val();
alert(textAreaValue);
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
alert ($("textarea[name=textEditor]").val()) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra semicolon need to remove.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(":submit").click(function(e){
     alert( $("textarea[name='textEditor']").val());
                                                  ^-- remove semicolon
      e.preventDefault();
     });
  });
```

Comment: There is no need for specifying the quotes if the attribute value is a single word.!

Comment: Yes ! single quote is not required :)